# Как создать форму для заполнения и сохранить введенные значения в url

Tags: java, java-ee, url, servlet

Был бы рад немного помощи в решении задачи:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделал решение с помощью html формы, но при сдаче задания, сказали, что необходимо html в Java коде написать.
Запутался, не могу понять как создать форму.

```
public class FirstServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {
static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";

protected void doPost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response)
        throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {

}

protected void doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response)
        throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String age = request.getParameter("age");
        String dateUrl = request.getParameter("date");

        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
    try{
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
        pw.println("Name : " + name + "\n" + "Age: " + age + "\n" + df.format(df.parse(dateUrl)));
    }catch(Exception e){
       pw.println("Invalid Date! Try use this format for Date dd.mm.yyyy");
    }
}
```

}

А вот сама форма html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как все совместить в java коде?
Так же , посоветовали использовать substring для создания формы.

Comment: Вроде написано все верно, только у формы в html не хватает параметра action и method. А как написать Html в java коде не представляю и думаю что ваше решение правильнее.